# Murex Application intercept network traffic

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, network-traffic

I am performing performance testing for  Murex desktop application, but not able to capture network traffic, can anyone assist if one has carried out testing for the same.

Thanks

Tried using Blazemeter Har to jmx conversion, HTTP toolkit, silkperformer ,loadrunner, jmeter traffic is not getting captured

Answer (score 0):

It is a question with the application architecture and it's communication protocol.

And all the methods you have tried is only related to http(s) protocol. What If the application doesn't use that protocol for communication?

A simple Google search returns that Murex desktop client uses RMI for it's communication. And it cannot be traced on http recorders. (Cross verify on the communication protocol with dev team)

You can write and invoke the same RMI calls via JSR223 sampler by importing the required libraries. All you need is a little help on the methods/calls being used or a documentation.

So, better reach the dev team for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Connectivity](https://www.murex.com/en/solutions/technology/connectivity) chapter of Murex documentation

> MX.3 supports all integration patterns and frequencies—real-time, event-driven and batch—and supports various financial messaging formats such as SWIFT, FpML or FIX.
>
> External middleware and systems connectivity is achieved using standard technologies such as Kafka, MQ, JMS, REST, WebServices, SFTP or JDBC.

As it evidenced by its name JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorded](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) can only record [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol so you will be able to cover only "REST" and "WebServices" and only with appropriate JMeter and operating system configuration. See [How to Do Desktop Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/desktop-performance-testing) article for more details.

With regards to [Kafka](https://pepperbox.gslab.com/), [MQ](https://activemq.apache.org/jmeter-performance-tests), [JMS](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html), [STFP](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler) and [JDBC](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) - you will need appropriate Samplers or Plugins, check out the links for more information. None of them can be recorded unfortunately.